# react fetch return undefined while in network tab its displaying but not showing on the page

Tags: reactjs

Data is coming but not displaying

[image]

[[image: Data is showing in the consel][2]]

Following is my useFetch code I just want to display the todo details

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
const useFetch = url => {
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
    getData();
}, []);
const getData = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(url)
        const data = await response.json();
        setData(data)
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error from Fetch:", error);
    }
  }
  return data;
 }
export default useFetch;
```

Comment: Can you console.log all the steps. And I would recommend to use react-query fur this exact use case. Check it out.

Comment: If there is no state updated in your compoennt, then it won't display anything when your fetch is done (If is asynchronous). You might need to add your result in a local state of your component.

Comment: No since the hook is used, that would trigger a state update. Even async

Comment: @Domino987 Ok wasn't sure about that, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are returning the todo as an object itself, you cannot extract it but use it as it is:

```
const todo = useFetch('http://localhost/todos/todosapi/todos/' + id);
```

Now you can access the properties.

If you want to destructe the return, you have to wrap the response once more:

```
const getData = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(url)
        const data = await response.json();
        setData(data)
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error from Fetch:", error);
    }
  }
  return {todo: data};
 }
```

To reduce the amount of calls you have to make and to cache data, check out react-query.

Answer (score 1):

At:

```
const { todo } = useFetch('http://localhost/todos/todosapi/todos/' + id);
```

You're trying to access property `todo` of the fetch response.

Based on the JSON response in the inspector network tab, it looks like there's no `todo` property. That might be why it is undefined.